# How to calculate the value of $\cos \theta$ if $\cos 3\theta$ is known

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\cos 3\theta = \frac{-11}{\sqrt{125}}$ then how can i calculate the the value $\cos \theta$ from there. I already tried so solve this by using $4\cos^3 \theta-3\cos \theta=\cos 3\theta $ but i was unable to solve the cubic equation.

Comment: Are you familiar with complex numbers? Because then you can just use $e^{3i\theta} = e^{(i\theta)^3}$

Comment: Yes But  sir from there also we need to calculate the value of \cos \theta

Comment: It seems that $\cos\theta={1\over\sqrt{5}}$ is a solution; but there are more.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, $\cos\theta = \left\lbrace\dfrac1{\sqrt5}, \dfrac{1}{10}\left(-\sqrt5-2\sqrt{15}\right), \sqrt{\dfrac35} - \dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\right\rbrace$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's answers are mathematically correct but poorly presented.  By using different radicals in the last two answers even though they come from the same factor of the cubic equation, WA obscures important properties such as all three roots summing to zero.  Come on WA, you can do bettr than that!

Answer (score 5):

The tricky part here is to put the cubic equation into a form where factors can be identified.  We could eliminate the radical by squaring the equation or by deriving an equation whose roots are squared, but these methods introduce extraneous roots.

The superior method is to render $\sqrt{125}=(\sqrt5)^3$ and with that, define $x=(\sqrt5)\cos\theta$.  Thereby

$4(x/\sqrt5)^3-3(x/\sqrt5)+11/(\sqrt5)^3=0$

Now the $\sqrt5$ appears to odd powers in all terms allowing it to be cancelled.  Clearing the remaining fractions then gives:

$4x^3-15x+11=0$

which can now be factored if the standard rational root search can give a root for $x$.  Finding the root $x=1$ we obtain the factorization

$(x-1)(4x^2+4x-11)=0$

and the quadratic roots are found by the usual methods.  Remember to render $\cos\theta=x/\sqrt5$ at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Since you know complex numbers:

$$e^{3i\theta} = e^{(i\theta)^3} $$

which leads to:

$$ cos(3\theta) + i \cdot  sin(3\theta) = (cos(\theta) + i \cdot sin(\theta))^3$$

Group the real and imaginary parts to get $cos(3\theta)$ and $sin(3\theta)$ as functions of powers of $sin(\theta)$ and $cos(\theta)$.

The equation you'll get for $sin(3\theta)$ will be a second-degree one. Use the identity $cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2 = 1$ when necessary.

Comment: After comparing these two equations we will get the same eq as  shown in question